# Rails 3 remote link displays RJS code on page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rjs

I have a Rails 3 app that uses a remote/AJAX link to update a partial on the page.  In my view, I have the following:

`<%= link_to 'link text', {:action => 'update_details'}, :remote => true %>`

That action in my controller has the following:

`render(:update) do |page|
      page.replace_html 'details', :partial => 'details'
    end`

Instead of updating  with the HTML in the 'details' partial it redirects to a page that prints the RJS code for doing that:

`try {
Element.update("details", "\nDetails\n\n");
} catch (e) { alert('RJS error:\n\n' + e.toString()); alert('Element.update(\"details\", \"\nDetails\n\n\");'); throw e }`

I don't get a Javascript error of any kind and I'm including all the necessary Javascript files, including Prototype.

Comment: Please make sure if javascript is enabled on your browser?

Comment: You might also want to place this code: page.replace_html 'details', :partial => 'details' in the controller_name.rjs file... to make it more Unobtrusive and easy to debug

Comment: Happens in multiple browsers with Javascript enabled.

Comment: Are you loading your csrf_meta_tag helper in the header?

Comment: Adding the helper code for the meta tags fixed the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please include csrf_meta_tag helper in the header..